# Code Block error with iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

After iOS 9 has released (Xcode 7.0), our app on the app store crashes intermittently, and when are trying to compile our codebase with iOS 9 we are seeing a compiler error in this piece of code

```
/* Check for dependent errors */
    __block NSError *dependentError = nil;
    [self.dependencies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomBaseOperationLoader *operation, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (operation.operationError != nil) {
            dependentError = [operation.operationError copy];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
```

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void
>   (^)(CustomBaseOperationLoader *__strong, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to
>   parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(NSOperation * _Nonnull __strong,
>   NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)'

iOS noob, anyone else facing this problem or know how to fix this? 
We weren't seeing it before the iOS 9 update, so something somewhere is deprecated.

And  `CustomBaseOperationLoader` extends `NSOperation` with some custom properties

UPDATE: 
Per below answer I changed method call to

```
__block NSError *dependentError = nil;
    [self.dependencies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^ _Nonnull(CustomBaseLoaderOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSUInteger  idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (operation.operationError != nil) {
            dependentError = [operation.operationError copy];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
```

Now I see :

> Control reaches end of non-void block

Update 2:
Added a return block, this seems to resolve the error
Is this the right way of handling this?

```
/* Check for depended errors */
    __block NSError *dependentError = nil;
    [self.dependencies enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^ _Nonnull(CustomBaseLoaderOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSUInteger  idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (operation.operationError != nil) {
            dependentError = [operation.operationError copy];
            *stop = YES;
        }
        return;
    }];
```

**UPDATE:**
Now xcode has just exploded with errors from this change on the lines of

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not sure where to go with this yet

Comment: I think the only answer to this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540701/xcode-7-gm-not-able-to-call-enumerateobjectsusingblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add nullability annotations.

```
 [yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^_Nonnull(id _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        //your stuff
    }];
```

Comment: Well I added _Nonnull to the method block itself, now I am seeing `Control reaches end of non-void block`

Comment: Resolved by adding a `_Nonnull` after the  `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` . Thanks. Also is it ok to add a return after the block to prevent `Control reaches end of non-void block` ?